# Ubuntu touch devel emulator not recognized by sdk ide

Tags: 15.04, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, scopes, ubuntu-emulator

I want to test my scope on an emulator, so I created an i386 emulator instance with the devel channel. I can start the emulator from inside the sdk ide and it will boot properly (I can unlock the device and run the default apps). However, the ide keeps thinking the device is still booting and displays the loading message, even after pressing the refresh button multiple times. So the ide cannot load my scope to the emulator.

How can I make sure the ide knows when the device is booted?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by enabling developer mode on the emulator itself:

Boot the emulator and got to `System Settings > About this phone > Developer mode` and click the switch button.